# Advancing Tzolk'in past the end of the game

Tags: tzolkin

In Tzolk'in, the starting player space lets one advance the calendar 2 days, instead of the normal 1.  The rules specify a few times when you cannot use this power, and what happens if the calendar is advanced past a Food Day.

But, the rules don't say anything about the possibility of this mechanic interacting with the end-of-game conditions.

So, what happens if you are in Turn 26, take the starting player space and advance the calendar 2 days?

Do you advance to Turn 28 and play out a 28th day?   That doesn't seem to make sense, as the game is only supposed to last 27 days.  (Note: this is what happens when you try this tactic on Board Game Arena)

Or, do you advance, skipping Turn 27, and just feed your workers before the end of the game.  This is the only way that the "advance 2 days" mechanic is useful in Turn 26.

Answer (score 3):

The rule for using this power right before any food day would still apply normally to the final food day of the game.

> It is not possible to use this privilege to avoid Food
> Days. If the next day on the Tzolk'in gear is a Food Day,
> you may still advance 2 days, but the new round will be
> the Food Day that was skipped over.

Turn 27 is a food day; it just so happens that it also is the final food day that ends the game. So you can turn the wheel 2 spaces, to 1 space past the final food day space, and then play the final turn like you normally would.

This matches what you say happens on Board Game Arena. I think it does make sense, because it’s not so much that the game is supposed to last 27 days, but rather that the game ends after the 4th food day. All food days normally happen on the indicated space on the wheel, but with the skip a day power and the quoted rule above, it is possible for a food day to take place 1 space later instead.

This can still be useful to do in turn 26, because it means that for the final turn, all workers are one space further along their wheels than they would have been otherwise. This could allow you to take an action that you couldn’t have otherwise, or also mess up your opponents' plans by forcing them to pay extra corn to take the action they were planning on taking.

The only way in which the power is different on turn 26 than at any other time in the game is that normally, the total game length is shortened by 1 turn for each time someone uses it, but that doesn’t happen if used at the end.

This interpretation was discussed and confirmed here: https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/910514/double-wheel-move-penultimate-space